# Creating Grid at Runtime through code in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, events

I have code as per attached that builds a Xamrin Grid virtually in code. The problem that I have not been able to resolve is Events that will be triggered when entering data into a cell.

Here is the output:
[Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko8Ut.png)
[Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir7PB.png)

The purpose of this post is to create an event that can be invoked to take action when data is entered into any of the cells created at runtime in the grid.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="VarGridSample.MainPage">

        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout
                Spacing="25"
                Padding="30,0"
                VerticalOptions="Center">

                <Label
                    Text="Variable Grid"
                    FontSize="32"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Label
                    Text="I am attempting to build a Grid at runtime to allow for variable rows and          columns. The Grid has been initially defined in the Content Page. The Grid is built in the code based on the number of rows and columns requested. Entry controls are built for each cell. The   problem is how to build the Events for each cell...ANY IDEAS?"
                    FontSize="18"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Entry x:Name="Rows"
                    Text="{Binding Rows }"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" Placeholder="Enter Total Rows" WidthRequest="150" />
                <Entry x:Name="Cols"
                    Text="{Binding Rows }"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" Placeholder="Enter Total Columns" WidthRequest="150"  />
                <Button x:Name="BuildGrid"
                    Text="Build Grid" HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="BuildGrid_Clicked" />
                <Grid x:Name="VarGrid">

                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage>
```

**Below is the C# code**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace VarGridSample
    {
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
       {
            private int rows { get; set; }
            private int cols { get; set; }
            private int cellcntr = 0;
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void BuildGrid_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                rows = Int32.Parse(Rows.Text);
                cols = Int32.Parse(Cols.Text);
                for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++)
                {
                    VarGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
                }
                for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++)
                {
                    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++)
                    {
                        var entry = new Entry
                        {
                        
                            Text = "cell" + (cellcntr).ToString(),
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                         };
                        VarGrid.Children.Add(entry, colIndex, rowIndex);
                        cellcntr++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What event do you want to trigger?  Why can't you just assign an event handler when you create the dynamic entry?

Comment: You provided some insight into the problem. I added the code entry.TextChanged += Entry_TextChanged; and the event is triggered. I was attempting to  set the trigger event within the  var entry = new Entry
                    {
                        
                        Text = "cell" + (cellcntr).ToString(),
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                    };

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
        private void BuildGrid_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rows = Int32.Parse(Rows.Text);
            cols = Int32.Parse(Cols.Text);
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++)
            {
                VarGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            }
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++)
            {
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++)
                {
                    var entry = new Entry
                    {
                        Text = "cell" + (cellcntr).ToString(),
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    };
                    
                    //add the event
                    entry.TextChanged += Entry_TextChanged;

                    VarGrid.Children.Add(entry, colIndex, rowIndex);
                    cellcntr++;
                }
           }
        }

        private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.OldTextValue);
            var entry = (Entry)sender;
            var parent= (Grid)entry.Parent;
            Console.WriteLine(parent.Children.Count);
        }
```